# Sikuli Integrator C# errors

Tags: c#, sikuli

I try to use Sikuli Integrator for C#.
I create new project in Visual Studio 2015, and I Install SikuliIntegrator.
After the installation `JSikuliModule.jar`, it will be part of my solution, together with some additional files. After that  Properties to set “Copy to Output Directory” property to “Copy always” of `JSikuliModule.jar`
 and then I try my code :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String pattern = @"C:\\Users\\amin-\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\SikuliTest\\SikuliTest\\img\\logo.png";
        SikuliAction.Click(pattern);
        //if (SikuliAction.Exists(pattern).IsEmpty)
        //{
        //    Console.WriteLine("Nope! It's gone...");
        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    Console.WriteLine("Yep! It's there...");

        //}
    }
}
```

If I run the code, this is the errors shows :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information: Access to the path 'C:\SikuliOutputLog.txt' is denied.

If I run the code as an administrator, this is the errors shows :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in SikuliModule.dl Additional information: ###FAILURE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manually create a text file  'C:\SikuliOutputLog.txt' then run the code.
It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows10 besides manually adding C:\SikuliOutputLog.txt you need also to make sure current user have the 'Write' control to this file.